# Is WM_DESTROY sent when user is logging out?

Tags: winapi

When a user logs out, does the app receive a `WM_DESTROY` message or only `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` / `WM_ENDSESSION`?   I save window placement on `WM_DESTROY` but doesn't seem to work on log out.  Although you think at some point the Window has to be destroyed ?

Comment: `WM_DESTROY` is the last even you'd get, by then maybe Windows thinks your app is taking too long to close and terminates it -- have you tried `WM_CLOSE`?

Comment: I'm sure you have read this, but in case you haven't: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/logging-off

Comment: @andy I did but it doesn't say anything about WM_DESTROY.  As far as WM_CLOSE, that for sure won't work, that is just a request to close and user can do what they want with it, default is to send WM_DESTROY message.

Comment: I would do what the docs say: If you get a `WM_ENDSESSION`, save your state. Do what you do in `WM_DESTROY`. Just don't depend on it as the system can do a "force logoff" where you get no notifications and you application is simply terminated without notice.

Comment: be nice if someone has a full flow chart of all the various window messages and how they flow.

Comment: FWIW `WM_NCDESTROY` comes after `WM_DESTROY` (in general that is, maybe not in this case).

Answer (score 0):

[`System Shutdown Messages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/system-shutdown-messages) in MSDN,I'm sure you have read them, but you need to pay extra attention to Remarks in [`WM_ENDSESSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/wm-endsession).

> Applications that have unsaved data could save the data to a temporary location and restore it the next time the application starts. It is recommended that applications save their data and state frequently; for example, automatically save data between save operations initiated by the user to reduce the amount of data to be saved at shutdown.
>
> The application need not call the `DestroyWindow` or `PostQuitMessage`
> function when the session is ending.

Comment: Yes, saw that but didn't know if it was saying the app didn't need to call `DestroyWindow` because it would.  But apparently not, so saving (in this case window position) needs to be done in both `WM_DESTROY` (or `WM_NCDESTROY`) and `WM_ENDSESSION`.

Comment: @user3161924 Could you tell me the detailed question you have now?Thanks.